# React Native ScrollView change height and scroll bottom

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I need to change height of ScrollView when I open a keyboard and then scroll bottom to show the TextInput. It works fine if I doesn't change height, but not when I change.

https://snack.expo.io/@kipris/talking-pretzel

Comment: have you tried KeyboardAwareScrollView ?

Comment: @Kailash no, but I'll try, thank you

Comment: @Kailash tried lib that you advised but it doesn't work with BottomSheet
https://github.com/ThakurBallary/react-native-btr/blob/master/docs/BOTTOM_SHEET.md